# listFiles() not shows files with few extensions in Android 11

Tags: android

Created folder (/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MyFolder) by me consists of two files with extensions .bin and .png. When works line **folder.listFiles()** the app shows the file with .png extension but doesn't show with .bin. Also doesn't show files of .txt, .rtf, etc if to throw them into my folder.

Such a problem exists only in Android 11+. For Android 10 and less all work well. How resolve this issue?

Comment: You do not have access to arbitrary files in arbitrary directories on Android 11+. If you need to support all MIME types, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` from the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: `if to throw them into my folder` You have not explained how exactly you did that. And certainly your app cannot create files with suchs extensions in that folder. Your app is not the owner of your 'thrown' files.

Comment: @blackapps I mean manually with Android File Transfer, for example.